# Tumblr Posting Failed in iOS with error 404 in iOS native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, tumblr

my issue is I can successfully logged in to tumblr However, unable to post on tumblr. 
Below is my code

```
 NSString *path = @"blog/myName.tumblr.com//post";            // set your Tumblr name here
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"type"  : @"text",
                                 @"title" : @"I'm On on Tumblr",
                                 @"body"  : @"Its going to be fun"};
    NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [OAuth1Controller preparedRequestForPath:path
                                                                  parameters:parameters
                                                                  HTTPmethod:@"POST"
                                                                  oauthToken:_oauthToken
                                                                 oauthSecret:_oauthTokenSecret];

    // Send the request and when received show the response in the text view
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:preparedRequest
                                       queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   self.promptView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                   if (error) NSLog(@"Error in API request: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                               });
                           }];
```

Below is my oAuthController implementation file where I set my ConsumerKey,ConsumerSecrete and callback URL

```
#define OAUTH_CALLBACK       @"tumblr_callback" //Sometimes this has to be the same as the registered app callback url
#define CONSUMER_KEY         @"MyKey"
#define CONSUMER_SECRET      @"MySecretKey"
#define AUTH_URL             @"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/"
#define REQUEST_TOKEN_URL    @"request_token"
#define AUTHENTICATE_URL     @"authorize"
#define ACCESS_TOKEN_URL     @"access_token"
#define API_URL              @"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/"
#define OAUTH_SCOPE_PARAM    @""
```

Below is the screen shot for the error I'm getting[image: Error]

Where am I doing it wrong. Please any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Code wise there are a few things you might want to look for here.

Are you able to use an oauth 'GET' request such as "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info"? If you can receive a successful 'GET' request then your access token is valid and you can look at how you're sending your post parameters.

**Make sure you are passing in your parameters as HTTP Body as well as signature parameters. Correct parameter ordering is likely provided by the library.**

```
NSString *postbody = @"body=myBodyText&type=text";

[oRequest setHTTPBody:[postbody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:TRUE]];
```

**
**Alternative solution****

Implement the [TumblrUploadr](https://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr)

To sum it all, I achieved login with GTM-OAuth and uploading with TumblrUploadr. For those who seek a solution to the Tumblr API.

**Update :** Some info concerning GTMOAuth, if you want to use the callback, you have to add a flag in the GTMOAuthAuthentication.m > +(NSArray*)tokenAuthorizeKeys : add kOAuthCallbackKey in the array so that it will be taken into account. Else, you have no callback.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the access token by get request. That is why I'm confused that what is wrong with my post method.